# Position h1, h2, and 2 images within header using flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm attempting to create a header for my website using html/css. This is what I have achieved so far:

[image: header]

That photo shows the entire header element with no parts cut off. I'm trying to get the images and both h1 and h2 to center, with the h1 and h2 centered vertically between the images. Additionally, I'd like the h2 to sit closer underneath the h1 much more than it is. Here is my current html/css:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
  font: 16px Geneva, Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  max-width: 1000px;
  color: #0D1B1E;
}

body > header {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #FAF9F4;
  height: 100%;
}

.first {
  padding: 5px;
  flex: 1;
}

.second {
  padding: 5px;
  flex: 3;
}

.third {
  padding: 5px;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<header>
      <div class="first">
        <img src="images/header-logo1.png" alt="Law Enforcement   Badge Logo" width="100" height="100">
      </div>
      
      <div class="second">
        <h1>On Scene Academy</h1>
        <h2>law enforcement training and tactics</h2>
      </div>
      
      <div class="third">
         <img src="images/header-logo2.png" alt="Law Enforcement Badge Logo" width="100" height="100">
      </div>
    </header>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I'm also open to using any other display or positioning methods other than flexbox. Thanks!

Comment: so what do you wanna do? center everything horizontally and vertically?

Comment: Yes, and I'd like the h1 and h2 to be centered horizontally and vertically in between the images. Does that make sense?

Comment: add `align-items: center` to your `header`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is solution. You need to use flex in header tag and add "align-items:center" property to make it center. As following;-

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
  font: 16px Geneva, Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
h1,h2{margin:0;}
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  max-width: 1000px;
  color: #0D1B1E;
}

body > header {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #FAF9F4;
  height: 100%;
}
header{align-items:center;}

.first {
  padding: 5px;
  flex: 1;
}

.second {
  padding: 5px;
  flex: 3;
}

.third {
  padding: 5px;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<header>
      <div class="first">
        <img src="images/header-logo1.png" alt="Law Enforcement   Badge Logo" width="100" height="100">
      </div>
      
      <div class="second">
        <h1>On Scene Academy</h1>
        <h2>law enforcement training and tactics</h2>
      </div>
      
      <div class="third">
         <img src="images/header-logo2.png" alt="Law Enforcement Badge Logo" width="100" height="100">
      </div>
    </header>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by explaining how your code fixed the problem. Using comments in the code is often a good idea as it it often hard to pick differences in two blocks of code.

Answer (score 0):

Is it something like this?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
  font: 16px Geneva, Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  max-width: 1000px;
  color: #0D1B1E;
}
/** Here is grid container **/
header {
  display: grid ;
  max-width: 100%;
  background: black;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr auto 1fr; /** this means 3 columns with first and third columns take up same space after the second column auto adjust in the center. **/
  grid-template-rows: 1fr; /* this means 1 row */
}

div.first {
  background: grey;
  grid-column-start: 1; /* this take the first column */
  justify-self: center; /* align inline row axis */
}

div.second {
  background: grey;
  grid-column-start: 2; /* this takes second column */
  align-self: center;   /* position at the center of the container.*/
}
div.second h1{
  background: white;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
div.second h2{
  background: white;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

div.third {
  background: grey;
  grid-column-start: 3; /* this takes third column */
  justify-self: center; /* align inline row axis. */
}
```

```html
<header>
      <div class="first">
        <img src="https://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/s--2m8vKwCk--/c_scale,f_auto,fl_progressive,q_80,w_800/17oyh0zri482jjpg.jpg" alt="Law Enforcement   Badge Logo" width="100" height="100">
      </div>
      
      <div class="second">
        <h1>On Scene Academy</h1>
        <h2>law enforcement training and tactics</h2>
      </div>
      
      <div class="third">
         <img src="https://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/s--2m8vKwCk--/c_scale,f_auto,fl_progressive,q_80,w_800/17oyh0zri482jjpg.jpg" alt="Law Enforcement Badge Logo" width="100" height="100">
      </div>
    </header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your images are decoration and not actual content. I'd look at removing them and adding them via psudo elements.

**Edit** - I've changed from absolute positioning to using `inline-block` to better handle vertical centering.

```css
body>header {
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #FAF9F4;
  min-height: 110px;
}


/*Common Stuff for psudo elements*/
body>header::before,
body>header::after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 5px;  
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}


/*Left Image - adjust url as required*/
body>header::before {
  background-image: url(https://fillmurray.com/100/100);
}


/*Right Image - adjust url as required*/

body>header::after {
  background-image: url(https://fillmurray.com/200/200);
}


/*Adjust margin on h1,h2 as you want less space there*/
body>header> div > h1 {
  margin-bottom: 0.1em;
}

body>header> div > h2 {
  margin-top: 0.1em;
}

/*Vertically center text*/
.headerContainer {
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
  /*And horizontal center title*/
  text-align: center;
  /*Limit width*/
  width: calc(100% - 240px);
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
  font: 16px Geneva, Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  max-width: 1000px;
  color: #0D1B1E;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="headerContainer">
  <h1>On Scene Academy</h1>
  <h2>law enforcement training and tactics</h2>
  </div>
</header>
```

**Or if you want to stick with flex**

```css
body>header {
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #FAF9F4;
  min-height: 110px;
  display:flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  /*Justify content so to elements are spaced "edege to edge"
    See: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/j/justify-content/
  */
  justify-content: space-between;
  /*Center the items in the row 
    See: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/align-items/
  */
  align-items:center;
}


/*Common Stuff for psudo elements*/
body>header::before,
body>header::after {
  content: '';
  flex:1;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 5px;  
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}


/*Left Image - adjust url as required*/
body>header::before {
  background-image: url(https://fillmurray.com/100/100);
}

/*Right Image - adjust url as required*/
body>header::after {
  background-image: url(https://fillmurray.com/200/200);
  /*The itme will grow with flex to set the image to the right*/
  background-position-x: right;
}


/*Adjust margin on h1,h2 as you want less space there*/
body>header> div > h1 {
  margin-bottom: 0.1em;
}

body>header> div > h2 {
  margin-top: 0.1em;
}


.headerContainer {
  flex:3;
/*And horizontal center title*/
  text-align: center;  
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
  font: 16px Geneva, Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  max-width: 1000px;
  color: #0D1B1E;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="headerContainer">
  <h1>On Scene Academy</h1>
  <h2>law enforcement training and tactics</h2>
  </div>
</header>
```

Or, you can get **Griddy** with it. Which has the simplest HTML of them all

```css
body>header {
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #FAF9F4;
  /*USe CSs Grid*/
  display: grid;
  /*3 Columns, 110px for each image, 1fr = remaining space*/
  grid-template-columns: 110px 1fr 110px;
  /*Two Rows*/
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  /*Min height is the size of the images+ a little padding*/
  min-height: 110px;
}


/*Common Stuff for psudo elements*/
body>header::before,
body>header::after {
  content: '';
  width: 100px;
  margin: 5px;  
  /*Our "bookend" images span 2 rows*/
  grid-row-start:span 2;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  /*Center the image*/
  background-position-y: center;
}


/*Left Image - adjust url as required*/
body>header::before {
  background-image: url(https://fillmurray.com/100/100);
  /*Start at the 1st column for the left image*/
  grid-column-start:1;
}

/*Right Image - adjust url as required*/
body>header::after {
  background-image: url(https://fillmurray.com/200/200);
  /*start at the last colum for the right image*/
  grid-column-start:3;
}

/*Center the header text and adjust the margins*/
h1,h2 {
  text-align:center;
  margin:0.125em;
  align-self: center;
}

header h1{
  /*Close up the spacing on the h1*/
  /*align-self: end;*/
}

/*POsition the h2 */
header h2 {
  /*On the second row*/
  grid-row-start:2;
  /*Starting at the 2nd colum*/
  grid-column-start:2;
}




* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
  font: 16px Geneva, Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  max-width: 1000px;
  color: #0D1B1E;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>On Scene Academy</h1>
  <h2>law enforcement training and tactics</h2>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for:

```css
header {
  display: flex;
}

.first,
.second,
.third {
  height: 50px;
}

h1,
h2 {
  font-weight: normal;
  padding: 0;
  /*margin: 0;*/
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="first">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" alt="Law Enforcement   Badge Logo">
  </div>

  <div class="second">
    <h1>On Scene Academy</h1>
    <h2>law enforcement training and tactics</h2>
  </div>

  <div class="third">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" alt="Law Enforcement Badge Logo">
  </div>
</header>
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/eqy2udch/) is the link to FIDDLE where you can verify this code.

Answer (score 0):

[image]I found a much easier, less code intensive way to achieve this. Here is what I did:

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: aquamarine
}

h1 {
  font-size: 40px;
  margin: 0px;
  text-align: center;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

img {
  margin: 10px 15px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <header>
      <img src="header-logo1.png" alt="#" width="100" height="100">

      <div>
       <h1>On Scene Academy</h1>
       <h2>law enforcement training and tactics</h2>
      </div>

      <img src="header-logo2.png" alt="#" width="100" height="100">
    </header>    
  </body>
</html>
```